# Which graphic card for supermicro X8DTi-LN4F motherboard?

Tags: graphics-cards, server, pcie, power

I plan to build workstation based on supermicro X8DTi-LN4F. I'm aware it's very old but I'm buying it in very decent money. The only problem with this mobo is lack pci-express x16.
According to the spec available on [supermicro site](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DTi-LN4F.cfm) it supports only pci-e x8 (means 25W limit), but looking at mobos picture it looks like one slot is x16 mechanically. Any ideas which card I may insert there without worries? I'm not going to run games on it, just desktop (probably some Linux of FreeBSD with Xmonad) usage but in 4k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a cheap GPU with DisplayPort 1.4 or HDMI 2.0. A GTX 1050 or RX 560 will do.

(edit, probably take one with a power connection if there is a 25W limit from the slot)